# AS3 Flash CS6 object Base class and Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I seem to be having a tiny bit of a problem, I'm createing a new movieclip as a variable with AS3, now the AS file is Monster.AS, with my object if i give it the base class as Monster and the class as Monster1, the monster code is ran, because I have a trace message, but it is not displayed on the screen, if i change the base class to flash.display.MovieClip and change the class to Monster, it runs the code and displays the enemy... I'm very confused on why it displays and doesn't display because of how the base class works, here is the code that creates the monster

This is the code snippet of Level.as

```
    public function Level( playerHero:HeroDisplay )
    {
        trace("Level code ran");
        monsterArray = new Array();
        heroGra = playerHero;
        addChild( heroGra );
        var newMonster = new Monster();
        monsterArray.push( newMonster );
        addChild( newMonster );
        setupLevel(1);
        //Buttons
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);
    }
```

this works for both, but as i stated above,
if Base Class = Monster
   Class = Monster1
wont be displayed
if Base Class = flash.display.MovieClip
   Class = Monster
will be displayed.

Anyone know why?

Canvas

More information,
Here is the image of the class + base class

[image]

Also here is the monster AS file

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Monster extends MovieClip
{
    public var id:Number;
    public var hp:Number;
    public var damage:Number;
    public var speed:Number;
    public var xPos:Number;
    public var yPos:Number;
    public var avaiableSkill:Number;

    public function Monster()
    {
        id = 1;
        monsterSetup();
    }

    public function monsterSetup():void
    {
        switch(id)
        {
            case 1: hp = 10; damage = 1; speed = 2; avaiableSkill = 0; this.x = 100; this.y = 150; trace("Monster Setup");
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does the class Monster (when you didn't see the graphics) extends MovieClip or Sprite?

Comment: Do you have a Monster or Monster1 class ? or is it just using the autogenerated class ?

Comment: my Monster class extends MovieClip, but Monster1 has no AS file what so ever

Comment: Would be interesting to see what is in the Monster Class

Comment: Extra information updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Monster class has no visual aspect.

Monster1, is what I am assuming has your monster artwork, correct ?

To use the Monster1 class you can use this code :

```
var newMonster:Monster1 = new Monster1;
addChild(newMonster);
```

I'm not really clear on what your approach is, but based on your setup you are never creating an instance of the visual element - which is the Monster1 class.